# Win10 Terminal / ssh to multiple panes How do I type one line in one pane and have it replicated in others

Tags: windows-10, command-line, ssh, terminal

I have just been making changes to three Raspberry Pis. To do so I ssh to each one via a cmd prompt and make an entry e.g.

```
usr@pi22:**~ $ sudo reboot
```

I then go to the next cmd prompt and type exactly the same and the next prompt etc.

Is there a way in WindowsTerminal to open for example three panes and make entries to three differing ssh sessions but all from just one pane?

Thereby reducing the number of keystrokes and time. The thing is this is so that I can always do the builds and keep them in sync with each other.

Comment: Any help please

Answer (score 0):

Well I have found a tool that does exactly what I was after. And for anybody who may need a similar tool go to the link below:
[The xTerm version has free and paid for versions](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/)

I was able to do what i needed with the free version, it has a menu item [Multi-Execution Mode]. I then decided the tool was good enough to purchase.